# Weird mapply behaviour: what have I missed?

Tags: r

The following code does not work as I expected:

```
a <- list(0, 1)
b <- list(0, 1)

# return a linear function with slope `a` and intercept `b`.
f <- function(a, b) function(x) a*x + b

# create a list of functions with different parameters.
fs <- mapply(f, a, b)

# test
fs[[1]](3)
# [1] 4  # expected zero!
fs[[2]](3)
# [1] 4
```

Can anyone tell me why?

NB: I've found a workaround, so I'm not looking for a different way to achieve the desired result.  But I'm curious as to why this particular approach didn't work.

---

**Update:**

As of R 3.2.0, this now works as expected:

```
a <- list(0, 1)
b <- list(0, 1)
f <- function(a, b) function(x) a*x + b
fs <- mapply(f, a, b)

# test
fs[[1]](3)
# [1] 0 
fs[[2]](3)
# [1] 4
```

Comment: +1 for finding this weird behavior! I love these things :-)

Comment: Might not be an *apply thing: `fs <- list(); for(i in 1:2) fs[[i]] <- f(a[[i]], b[[i]])` does the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[Update]** My initial analysis was correct but the conclusions were wrong :) Let's get to the conclusions after the analysis.

Here's some code demonstrating the effects:

```
x <- lapply(1:3, function(x) sys.frame(sys.nframe()))
x[[1]] # An environment
x[[2]] # Another environment
x[[3]] # Yet nother environment
x[[1]]$x  # 3!!! (should be 1)
x[[2]]$x  # 3!!  (should be 2)
x[[3]]$x  # 3 as expected

# Accessing the variable within the function will "fix" the weird behavior:
x <- lapply(1:3, function(x) {x; sys.frame(sys.nframe())})
x[[1]]$x  # 1
x[[2]]$x  # 2
x[[3]]$x  # 3
```

So the work-around in your case:

```
f <- function(a, b) { a;b; function(x) a*x + b }
```

Btw, as @James notes there is a `force` function that makes accessing a variable more explicit:

```
f <- function(a, b) { force(a);force(b); function(x) a*x + b }
```

**Conclusions**

Well, as @mbq and @hadley noted, this is due to lazy evaluation. It' easier to show with a simple for-loop:

```
fs <- list(); for(i in 1:2) fs[[i]] <- f(a[[i]], b[[i]])
```

The function `f`'s `x` argument will **not** get the *value* of `a[[i]]` (which is `0`), but the whole *expression* and the environment where `a` and `i` exist. When you access `x`, it gets evaluated and therefore uses the `i` at the time of evaluation. If the for-loop has moved on since the call to `f`, you get the "wrong" result...

Initially I said that this was due to a bug in `*apply`, which it isn't. ...but since I hate to be wrong, I can point out that *apply DOES have a bug (or perhaps more of an inconsistency) in these cases:

```
lapply(11:12, function(x) sys.call())
#[[1]]
#FUN(11:12[[1L]], ...)
#
#[[2]]
#FUN(11:12[[2L]], ...)

lapply(11:12, function(x) function() x)[[1]]() # 12
lapply(11:12, function(x) function() x)[[2]]() # 12
```

As you see above, the `lapply` code *says* it calls the function with `11:12[[1L]]`. If you evaluate that "later" you *should* still get the value `11` - but you actually get `12`!

This is *probably* due to the fact that `lapply` is implemented in C code for performance reasons and cheat a bit, so the expression that it shows is not the expression that gets evaluated - ergo, a bug...

QED

Comment: See `?force` for a similar example

Comment: It's not a bug. It's a consequence of lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 9):

This is the result of lazy evaluation -- all arguments are passed down the call tree as promises to avoid unnecessary execution and remain in this suspended state till R is convinced that they are used.

In your code you just populate functions with a same promise to a and same promise to b; then they all got committed to a last pair of vales. As @Tommy already showed, the solution is to force commitment by "using" the value before the function gets defined.